# How to make DataTables show only subset of columns then allowing others to appear by toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": false
    } );

    $('a.toggle-vis').on( 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );

        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );
} );
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swocnb4b/)** or **[DataTablesExample](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)**

Which produce the following table that allows user to toggle the six columns by clicking on the link next to `Toggle column`.

[image]

What I want to do then is to make the table to show only `Name` and `Position` column as default and hide the rest of columns. Only when the user toggle their preferred other columns then they will appear. How can this be achieved?

In reality I have ~50 columns to show. Currently it overflow the page.
Not sure what's the best way to display such case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With ColVis**

You need to use [ColVis extension](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) for Datatables.

Most likely you would want to hide some columns initially, you can do that using the code below.

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
   "dom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
   "columnDefs" : [          
       { "targets": [4,5], "visible": false }
   ]
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmbua7sb/) for demonstration.

Also ColVis extension allows you to [group columns](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/ColVis/examples/group_columns.html) and toggle group visibility instead of individual columns which could be helpful if you have 50 fields.

If you have that many fields, I would also consider showing [extra details](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) or [responsive extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) along with ColVis, you may be able to integrate these together.

**Without ColVis**

It can also be done without ColVis using the code below:

*HTML*

```
<p>Toggle: <a href="javascript:;" class="column-toggle" data-id="4">Start date</a> | <a href="javascript:;" class="column-toggle" data-id="5">Salary</a></p>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<!-- skipped -->
</table>
```

*JavaScript*

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": 'lfrtip',
    "columnDefs" : [          
        { "targets": [4,5], "visible": false }
     ]
});

$('a.column-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    var column = oTable.column($(this).data('id'));
    column.visible(!column.visible());
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmbua7sb/2/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the remaining information in the child table

see: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html[image: Child Table]

Comment: No. This is dealing with rows. My problem is the *column* overflow.